# Roth and Traditional 401k - Is it a valid strategy to withdraw from traditional for lower brackets, and then switch?

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, roth-401k

Given I am investing heavily in Roth 401k and also some in Traditional 401k...

I was wondering if it is a valid retirement strategy [after retiring] to withdraw the first couple lower tax brackets worth of income from the taxable traditional 401k thus taking advantage of lower rates, and then switching over to withdrawing from the tax-free Roth 401k for income that would normally be in the higher brackets and thus taxed at a higher rate.

Am I missing anything? I'm primarily trying to check my understanding; that is of taxable/non-taxable and progressive brackets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a valid strategy. You're not missing anything. In fact, you can only withdraw from the taxable source up to the RMD amounts and take all the rest from Roth, if you want.